Checking for right click in a java swing button using ActionEvent
In my project i have multiple buttons written in the format below:
private void j1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        buttonAction(evt, 1);
}

The buttonAction() is just a method I made which does whatever the button is supposed to do.
Is there anyway for me to use evt to find whether the user has pressed right click or left click.
Note: I have seen ways to use MousePressed() but this would require me to change my code lot.
I am looking for something like:
private void j1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        buttonAction(evt, 1);

        if (evt == *RIGHT CLICK VALUE*){
            System.out.println("Right click pressed!")
        }
}


As far as I can tell, there is not. This is because a JButton can be activated via the keyboard and programmatically and not just via the mouse.

With an ActionListener this isn't possible. What you can do is, to add a MouseListener (as you already mentioned) and handle the specific event(s) there as needed.

Can you explain why you need to know which mouse button was pressed?

A JToggleButton might be more appropriate and a better user experience.

@Abra I am making a minesweeper game. Each sqaure is its own button. Left clicking it would reveal it and right clicking it would place a flag over it.

Resolved by using Control + Click instead of Right Click, as there was no solution that I was looking for.
 private void j1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            buttonAction(evt, 1);
    
            if (evt.getModifiers() == 18){
                System.out.println("Control click pressed!")
            }
    }


Nah, just use a MouseListener similar to what I do with this 2011 MineSweeper program of mine.
